# Creat PDF file and emmbed actions within it in Python

Tags: python, pdf

I'm working in a project to analyze  and create PDF file.
I almost done with analysis part but I reached the part of creation pdf files.
is there any library or tool in Python I could use to create pdf and also to emmbed actctions within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several libraries that can create PDF files for different purposes. A couple of examples.

- The [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) library can generate plots in PDF format.
- The Python binding to the [cairo](http://cairographics.org/) graphics library, [pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/). Very good for drawing, but less suited for typesetting.
- [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/opensource/), written in pure Python.

Not really a library, but definitely an option;

- For high-quality typesetting, you can use Python to generate (La)TeX source code, which can be converted into PDF with [pdftex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PdfTeX). This requires that you have a TeX distribution installed though.

One way to embad actions in PDF files is to use javascript. E.g. [this TUGboat article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-3/tb72story.pdf) describes how to include javascript in PDF files generated with LaTeX.

Note however that not all PDF viewers support this.